# Angular4 --prod build Unexpected token error with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, three.js

Angular4 project and seeing the following error on prod build using command:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 'node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng' build --prod --output-hashing=al
```

Error:

> ERROR in vendor.422622daea37e6baf83f.bundle.js from UglifyJs
>   Unexpected token: name (BoxGeometry) [vendor.422622daea37e6baf83f.bundle.js:84218,6]

Running with `-sm` flag gives more detail:

> ERROR in vendor.422622daea37e6baf83f.bundle.js from UglifyJs
>   Unexpected token: name (BoxGeometry) 
> [MYAPPPATH/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js:12832,0]
> [vendor.422622daea37e6baf83f.bundle.js:84218,6]

The three.module.js:12832 line is:

```
class BoxGeometry extends Geometry {
```

...and then a small class definition.

Build without `--prod` flag works fine as you would imagine, as does `ng serve`.

I believe this may be caused by ES6 code in the ThreeJS plugin JS not being transpiled to ES5, but I am not sure how to resolve it.  I tried adding `"allowJs": true,` to tsconfig.json and that got rid of the error, but caused duplicate identifier errors in the tether plugin instead and from what I read that's not an ideal solution anyway.

Playing with the TS target version in tsconfig seems to get rid of the error, but again causes other errors.

I don't have an import statement in app.module.ts.  I am importing into the component that contains the ThreeJS code with the following:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "main-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.29",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^0.6.1",
    "@types/three": "^0.103.2",
    "angular-moment": "^1.2.0",
    "angular2-cookie-law": "^1.4.0",
    "angular2-ladda": "^1.2.2",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "aos": "^2.2.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.0",
    "gsap": "^2.1.3",
    "mobile-drag-drop": "^2.3.0-rc.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "three": "^0.110.0",
    "three-dragcontrols": "^0.88.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

package-lock.json webpack entry:

```
"webpack": {
      "version": "3.7.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/-/webpack-3.7.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-8MR+gVfxsvtx4J1UlbRGkUJEpDQUBFmisRmpPO5cVLgF21R8UMChX39OOjDz63a+m/iswGoqATszdZB2VCsYuA==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "acorn": "^5.0.0",
        "acorn-dynamic-import": "^2.0.0",
        "ajv": "^5.1.5",
        "ajv-keywords": "^2.0.0",
        "async": "^2.1.2",
        "enhanced-resolve": "^3.4.0",
        "escope": "^3.6.0",
        "interpret": "^1.0.0",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
        "json5": "^0.5.1",
        "loader-runner": "^2.3.0",
        "loader-utils": "^1.1.0",
        "memory-fs": "~0.4.1",
        "mkdirp": "~0.5.0",
        "node-libs-browser": "^2.0.0",
        "source-map": "^0.5.3",
        "supports-color": "^4.2.1",
        "tapable": "^0.2.7",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^10.4.6",
        "watchpack": "^1.4.0",
        "webpack-sources": "^1.0.1",
        "yargs": "^8.0.2"
      }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

What's my next step please?

Answer (score 0):

In case it's helpful to others, I solved this in the end by removing the three mode modules, downloading the precompiled version of three.js from github and including a reference to it in the angular-cli.json to include it and the other dependent scripts for three.js to work:

From angular-cli.json:

`...
"scripts": [
        ...
        "assets/libs/three/three.min.js",
        "assets/libs/three/GLTFLoader.js",
        "assets/libs/three/DragControls.js"
      ],
...`

You'll also need to add this to the top of your component:

`declare const THREE: any; // add an ambient declaration`

This now works fine, but I have lost all my lovely three typings, so it's not ideal.